# tomahawk schedule and javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, tomahawk

i'm doing a JSF application and have come up with an issue. Is it possible to integrate javascript functions with Tomahawk? Specifically, I want to flash a confirm dialog when a user clicks a t:schedule component. I tried it as

```
 submitOnClick="if(confirm('#{bundle.NewPatient}?'))return true; else return false;"
```

but the application does not respond.
Any ideas?
Thanks, Dave

Comment: Looks like the `<t:schedule>` tag does not support any DHTML events, see [documentation](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_schedule.html) and [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk/tomahawk20/1.1.10/org/apache/myfaces/custom/schedule/ScheduleTag.java?av=f) and submitOnClick takes just a boolean. You might want to put a feature request on their JIRA.

Comment: Hi Ravi! Yeah, that's what it looked like to me. I was hoping someone might have a work around. Oh well ... sigh.